# segmentation fault caused from terminal argument

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I try to get strings which may be a filename from terminal argument. I wonder why it would come to segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(char *argv[]){

    char somefile[sizeof(argv)];
    strncpy(somefile,argv[0],sizeof(argv));

    printf("The file name is: %s", somefile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) what do you expect  `sizeof(argv);` to be ?
2) what does `strncpy()` do if `(strlen(2nd_argument) >= 3d_argument)` ?

Comment: `int main(char *argv[])` is not a valid prototype for `main`

Comment: `int main(char *argv[])` is probably wrong, you should use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for a discussion of the correct signatures for `main()`. Hint: `int main(char *argv[])` is not a correct signature for `main()` on any normal platform — it should be `int main(int argv, char *argv[])` or equivalent (I use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` which is equivalent).

Comment: Great. I changed the arguments of main and it works. And also I found the comments about the length problem are also very helpful. Thx you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your statement:

```
strncpy(somefile,argv[0],sizeof(argv));
```

is handing the length of a pointer (i.e likely 4 or 8) to the 3rd argument instead of the actual size of the string.  Change it to:

```
char somefile[strlen(argv[0])+1]; // note extra space for NULL terminator...
strncpy(somefile,argv[0],strlen(argv[0])+1); // ...here as well
```

Note, `strncpy(dest, src, n)` (for example) copies at most `n` characters of the character array pointed to by src.  If `n` is reached before the entire array `src` was copied, the resulting character array, `dest` is not null-terminated.  To mitigate this potential, you may consider doing the following:

```
char src[] = "this string is too long";
char dest[10];
int n = 10;
strncpy (dest, src, n);
```

results in `dest` containing:

```
|t|h|i|s| |s|t|r|i|n|?|?|?|...// may, or may not have a null terminator somewhere.  

dest[n-1] = 0;
```

results in `dest` containing:

```
|t|h|i|s| |s|t|r|i|\0|?|?|?|...// guaranteed NULL termination.
```

And since `somefile` was created so specifically based on `argv[0]`

```
strcpy(somefile,argv[0]);
```

would do just as well in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

To get the length of argv you can just do `strlen(argv[0])` instead.

Everything is kinda compounding off of that major issue. `strncpy` should be using the length of the string, other than that it seems like it should work.

Comment: "strncpy should be using the length of the string,"  --> I would not use the length of the string as that guarantees the target is not a string.  Better to code base on the  size of the target array.